# Application does not respond to touches after running in background Cocos2D iPhone

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, touch

Currently I'm fixing an old Cocos2D iPhone 1.0 game. There is a strange problem: when the application is being sent to background by the four-finger gesture(iPad) after returning it behaves like the touch began and didn't end, and there no way to end it because the application does not respond to touches. Also when I launch the application and do nothing, the screen becomes locked and after that the application some times does not respond to touches.

I guess that there is something I need to do in the following  AppDelegate methods, but I can't figure out exactly:

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] pause];
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] resume];
}

    enter code here

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication*)application {
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] stopAnimation];
}

-(void) applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication*)application {
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] startAnimation];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in -(void)ccTouchCanceled method not implemented